# Add Callback to Dequeue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to add a callback after a dequeue in jQuery has been completed? If not, can you provide me with how to add a delay to a dequeue? Thanks a million!

Comment: The dequeue just jumps the queue, there is no callback for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a promise (http://api.jquery.com/promise/). Here is some code I (literally) just wrote which ensures that some divs are finished hiding before a show etc on them is started. The function passed into the done call on the promise will only get run after all the effects are finished. I put the next() (=>dequeue) call in there so the next queued item gets run.

```
<style>
#pieces { width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: lightblue;}
#pieces .piece { width: 75px; height: 75px; border: 1px solid grey; float: left;}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
var q = $({});;

function hidePieces() {
   q.queue(function(next){
      var pieces = $($("#pieces .piece").get().reverse());
      pieces.each( function(i) {
         $(this).delay(300*i).slideUp(1000);
      });
      pieces.promise().done(function(){ next(); });
   } );
}

function showPieces() {
   q.queue(function(next){
      var pieces = $("#pieces .piece");
      pieces.each( function(i) {
         $(this).delay(300*i).slideDown(1000);
      });
      pieces.promise().done(function(){ next(); });
   } );
}
$(function(){
   for( i=0;i<5;i++ ){
      hidePieces();showPieces();
   }
});
</script>
<div id="pieces">
<div class="piece" id="p1"></div>
<div class="piece" id="p2"></div>
<div class="piece" id="p3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Might need more info, but if you are trying to have some code called after a particular queued item is dequeued, you could wrap the original queued function with your own. For example, you could change from:

```
$("#xyz").queue(someFunction);
```

to this:

```
$("#xyz").queue(function() {
    someFunction();
    // your callback code here
});
```

I'm assuming that "someFunction" calls dequeue in order to keep the sequence going.

Comment: For sure this would work? I am looking for a dequeue callback, not after it's done loading the queue. Thanks!

Comment: The function passed to the queue function will be called when dequeue is called.